# Play Framework 2 Java using complex objects with HTML Forms

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

I couldn't find an example or a documentation that explains how to populate a complex object in a play.data.Form Object and reading the form's values later on in the Scala template.

BTW - I'm using java (I saw that Scala has some documentation about this but I'm using java)

By Complex Object I refer to:

Person entity  with Shopping Cart entity attached to it and with X Item entities in that cart :

person.cart.size
person.cart.item iteration
etc

A code example - is highly appreciated.

Thanks!
CB

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [Form sample](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/forms) included in Play.

In particular, you should be interested by the [Contact model](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/forms/app/models/Contact.java) and its [associated view](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/java/forms/app/views/contact/form.scala.html).